# Can't get z.rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to take rotation Z float, but I get unwanted number. Just watch screenshot

```
lastrot = transform.rotation.z;
```

[image]

Comment: Why did I get dislike?! If it's easy, just help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although, if you are using rotation, its better to use localEulerAngles.

```
lastrot = transform.localEulerAngles.z;
```

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: yep. this is it

Answer (score 1):

Rotation is a Quaternion. You are using the z of the quaternion, which is different from the z of the euler representation.

See : [Quaternion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html)

Additionally, if you want the same rotation, you should also use `localRotation` instead of the absolute `rotation`.

So, you should use :

lastrot = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z;